# React - state property is undefined - Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to load all companies via AJAX request into a `state` property when the user clicks on the `select` box.

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SelectOption from './SelectOption';

class CreateFreightEntryModal extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            freights: props.freights,
            onClose: props.onClose,
            onClick: props.onClick,
            companies: [],
        };
    }

    loadCompanies(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            context:this,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            url: "../data/get/json/companies",
            data: ({ 
                _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; });
                this.setState({
                    companies: arr
                })
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="modal fade" id="createFreightEntryModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 className="modal-title">New freight entry</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <form onSubmit={this.add.bind(this)}>
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                                <strong>Create a new freight entry:</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                                Company
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                                <div className="form-group" onClick={this.loadCompanies.bind(this)}>
                                                    <select className="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" data-title="Please select" ref="Firma" required>
                                                    {
                                                        this.state.companies.map((company)=> {
                                                          return (
                                                            <SelectOption value={company.Nummer} displayValue={company.Bezeichnung} key={company.id} />
                                                          );
                                                        })
                                                    }
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CreateFreightEntryModal
```

When I add the `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` method, I get this error.
This error occurs when the page is loaded and not when I click on the select box!

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
        companies: nextProps.companies,
    });
}
```

> TypeError: this.state.companies is undefined

This is the part where the error occurs:

```
...
this.state.companies.map((company)=> {
...
```

How can I solve this issue? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do a `console.log( data )` in the `success` callback to see what you actually get from the backend.

Comment: Obviously, because `nextProps.companies` is `undefined`. Since you don't show us where you're using the component, we can't help you more than that, because we can't see the props you're using when you use it. Remember: props are not state. In fact, [the documented purpose](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) of `componentWillReceiveProps` is to give you a chance to make props state if you want to.

Comment: @pawel: It won't be there, because that's **state**, not props.

Comment: You can see all used props in the constructor. @pawel I forgot to tell that this error occurs when the page is loaded and not even when I click on the select box!

Comment: Oooh it may be simpler than I thought. The success callback has the `jQuery` scope, should have been defined as `success: data => { this.setState() }`

Comment: Check `console.log(arr)` before `setState` in success.

Comment: @Andrew  The error comes up when the page loads, not when the ajax result is loaded.

Comment: @dns_nx is `nextProps.companies` the same `arr` in ajax, as you expected? Or from where it come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this construct:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
        companies: nextProps.companies,
    });
}
```

you update `state.companies` every time the component receives **ANY props**, even when there are no `companies` in the props. And when the `nextProps` don't have `companies` it is set to `undefined`.

Let's illustrate it this way:

```
{
  let props = { freights : [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] }
  this.setState({ companies : props.companies }) 
  /* state.companies are now undefined, because props.companies are undefined */
}
```

Fix:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if( nextProps.companies ){
      this.setState({
          companies: nextProps.companies,
      });
    }
}
```

BTW the problem with success callback scope I have mentioned in a comment may still apply.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The error has gone now, but the companies are still not added to my select box. I changed also the jquery scope. The ajax result seems to be okay. But this maybe another problem. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: The ajax problem may be related to `this` not being the component in the `success` callback, because in jQuery it's the `jqXHR` request object. So you try to execute `setState` on the wrong thing. Refactor the success callback to an arrow function.

Comment: On that ajax problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: In the jquery ajax i set `context: this`. I've just checked that. In the `success` I see als props, refs and state variables, so I assume this is the correct `this`.

Comment: @dns_nx sorry, I missed that you set the context. In this case I really have no better idea than trying to force rendering after the state is set, i.e. `this.setState({ companies : arr }, this.render)` and see what happens.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the bootstrap-select box. I can see that in the original `select` box all entries are there, but I think, I have to re-render the bootstrap-select box.